# Prove that for real numbers $x$, if $x^2 - 5x + 4 \ge 0$, then either $x \le 1$ or $x \ge 4$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Its another homework question that I'm having trouble understanding.

The full question is write a detailed structured proof that uses a proof by cases to prove that for real numbers $x$, if $x^2 - 5x + 4 \ge 0$, then either $x \le 1$ or $x \ge 4$.

You may use without proof the fact that:

$\forall a \in \mathbb R, \forall b \in \mathbb R, [(ab \ge 0) \longleftrightarrow (((a \ge 0) \wedge (b \ge 0)) \vee ((a \le 0) \wedge (b \le 0)))]$.

I actually don't understand what is going on here $\forall a \in \mathbb R, \forall b \in \mathbb R, [(ab \ge 0) \longleftrightarrow (((a \ge 0) \wedge (b \ge 0)) \vee ((a \le 0) \wedge (b \le 0)))]$.

I know that $x^2 - 5x + 4 \ge 0$, then either $x \le 1$ or $x \ge 4$ can be factored with the quadratic equation to give me $x^2 - 5x +4 = (x-1)(x-4)$.  I also know that I can use $(x-1)(x-4)$ in the place of $ab \ge 0$, where $a$ would most likely be $(x-1)$, and $b$ being $(x-4)$.

What's throwing me off is it says $((a \ge 0) \wedge (b \ge 0)) \vee ((a \le 0) \wedge (b \le 0))$.  My math is rusty admittedly and I don't understand why both $a$ and $b$ both need to be $\ge \vee \le$.  I'm unable to actually start the homework question because I don't understand what it's trying to tell me.  Can anyone help me understand/clarify it for me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546145/proof-of-consequneces-of-a-quadratic-inequality

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm getting your exact question regarding a>=0,b>=0, but isn't the statement you reference just saying that ab>=0 iff a and b are both positive or a and b are both negative?

Comment: should I copy and paste my question over his or append it at the bottom? Not sure what the proper etiquette is for doing question editing.  I'm not asking for the proof, but for some help understanding the question part of it. to njguliyev


I think you nailed it GAM, not sure why I didn't notice that before, thanks for the comment there.

Comment: As far as I can tell the OP is asking why for $ab\ge 0$ to be true, $a,b$ have to have the same sign.

Comment: haven't gotten that far yet git gud, was brain farting on the both a and b are both positive or negative

Comment: @MarshmellowJello What I said is what you said in different words.

Comment: Do you know that negative times positive is a negative number?

Comment: @GitGud, what I meant was that you cleared up my confusion.  I completely overlooked the both being positive or negative fact which lead to my confusion of looking for something deeper there.  And yes I do, but I'll be back in a few minutes.  I want to give this question a shot first incase I read the answer by mistake.

Comment: @MarshmellowJello Is all good then?

Comment: @GitGud all good, now I'll start doing the question myself.  I'll be back if I get confused after giving it a go. thanks for the help.

Comment: @MarshmellowJello No problem. If you realise that you understood the problem, it's recommended that you yourself post an answer so the question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: @GitGud thanks for all the help, I'm going to answer it now.  turns out the actual question was rather easy once you knew what was going on in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The symbolic statement that you are allowed to use without proof is simply saying nothing more than "if the product of two terms is positive, then either they are both positive, or they are both negative".

So with that in mind, You want to take this thing which you have clearly factored,
$$(x-1)(x-4) \geq 0,$$

and consider cases. One way might be to find critical values where

$$(x-1)(x-4)=0.$$
Clearly these are $x=1$, or $x=4$. Now test a case for each region in $x<1$, $1<x<4$, and $x>4$. You are of course looking for the positive regions. Your solution will follow from this effort.

Comment: Nice explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

$x^2-5x+4=(x-1)(x-4)\ge0$.  So in order for the expression to be positive it has to be the product of two positive numbers or two negative numbers (which the hint states). If it is the product of two negative numbers what is the inequality for x? If it is the product of two positive numbers what is the inequality for x?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was that the notation says both $a$ and $b$ need to be positive OR negative, no positive and negative, but both at the same time.  And after reading this highschool calculus should be flooding back into your head.